# A href around table is not working in internet explorer

Tags: html

I want a clickable table. This code works in all browsers, except in IE8. I haven't tested in IE9, but it works in IE10. By not working I mean nothing happens when I click on the table. Why?

```
<a href="www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="nonlink">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>hello</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

This works of course:

```
<a href="www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="nonlink">
  hello
</a>
```

I tested the code in a clear webpage where no other code exists.

Comment: `A` is an inline element. `table` is a block level element. Your HTML is invalid because inline elements should't contain block level elements. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I suppose an alternative is a JS `onclick`?

Comment: JS onclick event may cause bad behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, but it's definitely not good practice. From your example you should be able to include the anchor in the cell.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="nonlink">hello</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49Fen/) for a demo.

Comment: Yeah, I have just tried it out on another one of my websites. Looks like I have a long night ahead of me

Comment: I did but then it doesn't work when I click to an empty space of the table where there is no text

Answer (score 2):

It'll obviously wont work since you using iligal way.
You cannot use `<a>` tag outside table tag.

However you can allways use `<a>` inside `<p>` tag so the code will be vaild, like that:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><a href="www.cnn.com" target="_blank" class="nonlink">hello</a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**EDIT**

Here is an alternative way for your code so the table empty space will be fixed.

```
$('td').on("click", function(){
    window.location = ""; // Add whatever your window location (I.E. index.html)
});
```

Comment: This is a workaround and it doesn't work when you click on empty space of the tablem where there is no text.

Comment: Well you can allways use jQuery for that, I'll update my code for something more usefull for you.

Comment: @erdomester You shouldn't use a table at all if it's a layout issue. Use CSS to make your `a` the correct size (by making it a block level element). That will eliminate the spacing issues. Again if you would edit your question to clearly state what you're trying to accomplish you'll get better answers here.